# What is the architecture behind the Keras LSTM cell?

Tags: keras, lstm

I am doing a project about sequence model.  When I read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04069.pdf?utm_content=buffereddc5&utm_medium=social&utm_source=plus.google.com&utm_campaign=buffer), I found there are lots of variants of LSTM.  what confuses me is that I am not clear the architecture behind the Keras when using [LSTM cell](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/). Can someone tell me which LSTM architecture used in Keras? Is [picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHNrZ.jpg)？ or [picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZql.jpg)? or others?

[image: picture-1]
[image: picture-2]

The version of Keras I used is 2.1.5.

Answer (score 4):

From the [source code for LSTMCell](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py/#L1689), in the `call` method we can see the answer. (The `call` method of a cell is the calculation for "one step").

**It's the first implementation** with some hidden steps.

Showing:

As inputs to the call method, there are `inputs` which is `h(T-1)(L-1)` in the pictures; and `states` which contains both `h(T-1)(L)` and `C(t-1)(L)` in a tuple.

Initially, the inputs will be preprocessed with a kernel and bias, and be called `X`, separated in `i, f, c, o`, corresponding to the same letters in the images. This step is not in the picture.

```py
x_i = K.dot(inputs_i, self.kernel_i)
x_f = K.dot(inputs_f, self.kernel_f)
x_c = K.dot(inputs_c, self.kernel_c)
x_o = K.dot(inputs_o, self.kernel_o)
if self.use_bias:
    x_i = K.bias_add(x_i, self.bias_i)
    x_f = K.bias_add(x_f, self.bias_f)
    x_c = K.bias_add(x_c, self.bias_c)
    x_o = K.bias_add(x_o, self.bias_o)
```

These will be the true `h(T-1)(L-1)`.

The state `h(T-1)(L)` will also be split in four, but just for code readability, I guess, without any preprocessing:

```
h_tm1_i = h_tm1
h_tm1_f = h_tm1
h_tm1_c = h_tm1
h_tm1_o = h_tm1
```

Now, the lower part of the picture. Where you see `sigmoid` in the picture, keras uses `recurrent_activation`; and where you see `tanh`, keras uses `activation`.

But keras recurrent kernels (recurrent weights) are applied only to `H` (that is `h(T-1)(L)`), not to `X` (which is `h(T-1)(L-1)`). (Because `X` had different dimensions and needed to be preprocessed with another kernel as shown above).

The arrows in the picture calculated in keras code:
(considering that `c_tm1` is `C(T-1)(L)` in the image)

```py
#line i in the picture - C does not participate here
i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(h_tm1_i, self.recurrent_kernel_i))

#line f in the picture - C doesn't participate here either
f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(h_tm1_f, self.recurrent_kernel_f))

#upper C line + lower C line
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(h_tm1_c, self.recurrent_kernel_c))

#line o in the picture - C doesn't participate here as well    
o = self.recurrent_activation(x_o + K.dot(h_tm1_o, self.recurrent_kernel_o))
```

Finally, there is the final multiplication:

```
h = o * self.activation(c)
```

The outputs will be `return h, [h, c]`, showing `h(T)(L)` both as output and as a state to the next step. `C` will also be a state to the next step.

**Remark:**

All multiplication symbols in the picture are "elementwise" multiplications in keras.

Comment: The [LSTM documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) has references to the papers it implements, for example how and why dropout is applied in the way it is.

Comment: Whats notable is that keras uses a "hard sigmoid" for their LSTM https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/hard_sigmoid